# Echo the basename in shell

Tags: shell

I have a path to the directory and I need to extract the filename out of it so that I can use further in the shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
dir=/var/tmp/file1
fname= basename $dir 
echo $fname
echo "The script executes:" $fname 
echo $fname
```

Here the fname gets printed only once. In all other cases, it comes as blank.

Where is it that I am going wrong?

Comment: `fname= basename $dir` should be `fname=$(basename "$dir")`. Perhaps you should read a tutorial or manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below is working.

```
#!/bin/sh
dir=/var/tmp/file1
fname=`basename $dir`
echo $fname
echo "The script executes:" $fname
echo $fname
```

> **output** $: ./tt.sh
>
> file1
>
> The script executes: file1
>
> file1

Comment: I used it in this manner, but now in this case, file1 is getting executed. :(

Comment: @user2403449 Not if you did it *exactly* like that. Note that spaces around the `=`s make a *huge* difference.

Comment: @my-thoughts `$()` is preferred over backticks these days. And although not strictly necessary in this case, variables should be quoted as a rule.

Answer (score -1):

Some more points to add on top the above answers.

If u want only the filename without any extensions

use below command

**basename filename.type .type**